# Prevent PageBreak between Elements C# (Open-Xml)

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I want to "bind" two tables, with an empty paragraph in between in OpenXML Word. And prevent a pagebreak between them. So when inserted in the document, they appear on one page, and not on two. Writing it in one Table is unfortunately not an option.

It works to prevent a pageBreak between the empty paragraph and the following table.

Like this:

```cs
breakParagraph.Append(new ParagraphProperties(new KeepNext(), new KeepLines()));
```

However, this does not work when I want to prevent pageBreak between the previous table and the empty paragraph.

Adding ParagraphProperties, oder TableProperties with KeepNext, or KeepLines, does not work.

Please let me know, if you know something. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you use one table, with no (side) borders for the row that separaates them? Or nest two tables in a one-cell table (with a paragraph between)? Another possible solution would be to format the tables as "floating" - then there's a property (as I recall) that will prevent them from breaking to another page (although the paragraph between might be a problem, but if they're floating, that paragraph may not be necessary). Play around with these options in the Word Ui. When you find one that works best inspect the Open XML in the Productivity Tool.

Comment: OK ! Thank you, I'll try to nest them in another table. Maybe that's a good workaround. - and I'll try out this floating property as well.

Comment: @Jon If you do this task in Word itself you need to set the keep with next property for the last row of the first table and the paragraph marker between the two tables.